# Throw New NotImplementedException - VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm making an application that manages the inputs and outputs of a company's customers as well as the creation of the same, however when I "submit" the form of the creation of a new customer to me the following error:

"Throw New NotImplementedException"

I leave here my code, so they can help me.

FORM1.vb

```
Public Class Form1

Private Property cnt As Object

<SerializableAttribute> _
'<ComVisibleAttribute(True)> _
Public Class NotImplementedException _
'Inherits SystemException


End Class




Private Sub TabPage1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim cnt As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub GroupBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage2
End Sub

Private Sub TabPage2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabPage2.Click

End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'cnt.ConnectionString = "Provinder=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.40; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\bdtesteentradas.mdb"
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'BdtesteentradasDataSet.empresa' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.EmpresaTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BdtesteentradasDataSet.empresa)

End Sub

Private Sub FillByToolStripButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FillByToolStripButton.Click
    Try
        Me.EmpresaTableAdapter.FillBy(Me.BdtesteentradasDataSet.empresa)
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Me.EmpresaBindingSource.Filter = "nif ='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox6.Text = ""
    TextBox7.Text = ""
    TextBox8.Text = ""
    TextBox5.Text = ""
    TextBox4.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click



    'Dim cnt As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    If Not ConnectionState.Open Then

    End If

    Cmd.Connection = cnt()
    Cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO empresa (NIF, Empresa, nCliente, Distrito, NomeContacto, ApelidoContacto, Funcao" &
      "VALUES(" & Me.TextBox6.Text & ")"
    'Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox("Dados inseridos.")




End Sub
```

Cmd.vb

```
Class Cmd

Shared Property CommandText As String

Shared Property Connection As Object
Shared Sub ExecuteNonQuery()
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Sub
```

End Class

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvhnE.png)

Already a big thank you

Comment: remove `Throw New NotImplementedException` from `ExecuteNonQuery()` function of `Cmd` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got error on your "cmd" variable and "fixed it" this way:

[image: fix1]
[image: fix2]

Didn't you? This generated the file `Cmd.vb` for you.

That is not what you want. Remove `Cmd.vb` from you project an try this:

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        'You want to check, what the State of *your* connection is
        If Not cnt.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

        End If

        'Create a Command-Object from the Connection
        Using cmd = cnt.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO empresa (NIF, Empresa, nCliente, Distrito, NomeContacto, ApelidoContacto, Funcao" &
              "VALUES(" & Me.TextBox6.Text & ")"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MsgBox("Dados inseridos.")

        End Using

    End Sub
```